# Iterating through a list which is an object of a table

Tags: java, list, spring-mvc, object, iteration

```java
public List<AnswerValues> getAllAnswers(Forms fm){
     Session sess = getSession();
     Criteria crit = sess.createCriteria(FormQuestions.class);
     crit.add(Restrictions.eq("fkformId",fm));
     List<FormQuestions> qs = crit.list();
}
```

The code is incomplete. I want to do the below operation on the list qs.

```java
FormQuestions fq;
fq.getFormsId();
```

How can I perform the above operation from the list?

I'm a beginner to java spring, any help will be considered a big help.

Comment: Do you want to create a list of all "forms ids"? What is the data type of the formsId (long, String, something else)?

Comment: No that's not of relevance. What I'm trying to achieve is do the operation on the FormQuestions list object qs, like I did on the FormQuestions object fq

Comment: It looks like "the operation" you are doing on FormQuestions is "getFormsId()", is that right? If that is the case, List does not have a "getFormsId()". If that is not useful maybe you could describe more specifically what you are hoping to accomplish.

Comment: The list qs is of type FormQuestions. FormQuestions is a table. getFormsId() is a getter function of the table. So how can I using this getter function on the table object which is a list of objects? Sorry for the late reply, was out of network zone. And I hope this adds more clarity to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `getFormsId` is a getter (as you state in the comments):

```java
qs.stream().map(fq -> fq.getFormsId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

will get you a list of whatever `getFormsId` returns from each of the `FormQuestions`.